# What is the class name of the discord chatbox input field?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to get the class name of the discord input field, but the class name is not `input` and is some long class name that I'm not sure what it is.

[image]

Here is the class name:

```
markup-2BOw-j slateTextArea-1Mkdgw fontSize16Padding-3Wk7zP
```

What is the name of that input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've found the class attribute you can see that it has multiple class names. They appear to be dynamically generated through some variant of CSS-in-JS (this is quite common for SPAs) and are thus relatively unpredictable.

If you've found that then you should be able to see that it isn't an `<input>` but is a `<div>` with `contenteditable="true"`.

It doesn't have a `name` (such things are invalid on `<div>` elements) and data entered into it will be processed with client-side JS.